# How to run shell script with C# on OSX?

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine

I'd like to use C# to execute a shell script. 
Based on similar questions I came to a solution that looks like this.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app","sunflow/sunflow.sh");
```

It currently opens Terminal, then opens the shell file with the default application (Xcode in my case). Changing the default application is not an option, since this app will need to be installed for other users.

Ideally the solution will allow for arguments for the shell file.

Comment: no access to my mac here, but try the launch or open commands

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can't test with a Mac right now, but the following code works on Linux and should work on a Mac because Mono hews pretty closely to Microsoft's core .NET interfaces:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "foo/bar.sh",
    Arguments = "arg1 arg2 arg3",
};
Process proc = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = startInfo,
};
proc.Start();
```

A few notes about my environment:

- I created a test directory specifically to double-check this code.
- I created a file bar.sh in subdirectory foo, with the following code:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  for arg in $*
  do
      echo $arg
  done
  ```
- I wrapped a `Main` method around the C# code above in Test.cs, and compiled with `dmcs Test.cs`, and executed with `mono Test.exe`.
- The final output is "arg1 arg2 arg3", with the three tokens separated by newlines

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Adam, it is good starting point for me. However, for some reason when I tried with above code (changed to my needs) I am getting below error

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Exec format error
```

see below code that gives above error

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
               {
                       FileName = "/Users/devpc/mytest.sh",
                       Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}",  "testarg1", "testarg2", "testarg3", "testarg3", "testarg4"),
                       UseShellExecute = false,
                       RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                       CreateNoWindow = true
                   };
                  Process proc = new Process()
                  {
                    StartInfo = startInfo,
                  };
                   proc.Start();
                   while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                   {
                       string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                       //do something here
                   }
```

and spent some time and come up with below and it is working in my case - just in case if anyone encounter this error try below

Working Solution:

```
  var command = "sh";
    var scriptFile = "/Users/devpc/mytest.sh";//Path to shell script file
    var arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}",  "testarg1", "testarg2", "testarg3", "testarg3", "testarg4");
    var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = command,
        Arguments = arguments,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true

    };

    Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);   // Start that process.
    while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    {
        string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        // do something here
    }
    process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Where do you put that `scriptFile`? It's lost in your example.

Answer (score 2):

I spent *several months* struggling with this issue on and off, and I finally arrived at a solution. I scoured dozens upon dozens of forums, and nothing worked for all of my needs. I only arrived at answer when I finally decided to try using `osascript`.

**Context**: I'm working in Unity, and I'm running an automatic build pipeline from the editor, which publishes using Itch.io's "butler" command line tool.

I needed my tool to **open a new terminal window**, and run a shell script **with arguments**. Here's my solution:

```
public static void RunShellScriptOSX(string scriptPath, string arguments = null)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = "osascript",
        Arguments = $"-e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to activate' -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"sh {scriptPath} {arguments}\"'",
        
        UseShellExecute = true,
        CreateNoWindow = false,
        Verb = "runas",
        RedirectStandardOutput = false,
        RedirectStandardInput = false,
    };
    Process process = new Process()
    {
        StartInfo = startInfo,
    };
    process.Start();
}
```

Calling context:

```
[MenuItem("Build/Mac (Dev)/Publish")]
public static void PublishMacBuild()
{
    // ...

    // Run the shell script.
    string arguments = string.Format("'{0}' '{1}'", buildFolderPath, versionNumberFilePath);
    RunCommandScript("Builds/Mac/Butler_Publish.command", arguments);
}
```

I was able to get this working on both `.sh` and `.command` scripts.
My `Butler_Publish.command` shell script looks like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Build Folder Path: $1"
echo "buildnumber Path: $2"
butler push "$1" myItchUserName/my-project:mac-dev --userversion-file "$2"
read -p 'Press [Enter] key to continue...'
```